# Hover Popup does not move when parent node scroll left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

there. I was trying to make a hover popup. When my mouse hovers over a table header, a detail explanation will pop up.
However, when I scroll left the table, the popup stays. Is there any way that I can make it stick with the header?

Jsfiddle Link:
https://jsfiddle.net/fmchen/hmaczn87/10/

Some Screenshots:
[image]

When scroll left:
[image]

I know that I can change the `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;` in `.CellComment1`
However, it will be looking like this:
[image]

Comment: create a fiddle and add u r code so that it will be easier to understand u r problem.

Comment: Hi @DeepshikaS, I have edited my question and made a dummy HTML. You will see the problem if you scroll left and hover over the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the position: relative; to the field_29 class, then position: absolute; to the span and it worked properly. If you want to be in 1 row then add the span a width: max-content; and for the center align add a margin-left: 50%; and transform: translateX(-50%);

```
.field_29:hover span.CellComment{   display: block;   position: absolute;   width: max-content;   margin-left: 50%;   transform: translateX(-50%); }

.field_29 {   position: relative; }
```

Comment: Hi @Ronald, Thank you for your help. This is exactly what I want. However, I am missing one important piece in my CSS. which is `th {
    overflow: hidden;`  I guess this causes the problem. DO you have any thoughts?

Comment: I made a new JsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/fmchen/hmaczn87/15/

Comment: OMG, I figure it out! just set overflow to visible.

Comment: Hi @Chen-CN, I don't think it's a good idea because the apan is out of the th, so it won't be visible. What's your remaining problem exactly? sorry for my english btw.

Comment: Oooh I see yeah it will work properly now I think :D